# backbone calculations between models

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm working my way through a project using Marionette.js but I have come to a roadblock. 
my models represents a leg of a trip driven by a delivery person.  Each model has
pick_location, pickup_time, drop_location, drop_time

I need to be able to not only calculate the distance traveled during the delivery but also between deliveries.  So that if

- d1 - pick_loc-1, pick_time-1, drop_loc-1, drop_time-1, ....
- d2 - pick_loc-2, pick_time-2, drop_loc-2, drop_time-2,...etc

I want to produce a display of

- d1 -  travel_time (pick to drop), travel_distance (pick to drop)
- travel_time between deliveries,   travel_distance between deliveries
- d2  travel_time (pick to drop),   travel_distance (pick to drop)

then sum the columns when done.

the sum at the end I'm thinking could be easily accomplished with a collection.reduce definition

the calculation of time and distance between locations within the model should be straight forward.

the hangup I'm having is calculating the intermediate values that involve calculations between models and displaying the calculated rows in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're essentially presenting the same information in each row:

```
| Context | Travel Time | Travel Distance |
```

Where Context is either a delivery or a transit. You could invoke a bit of trickery when you're creating your collection by injecting new objects into your collection that represent the transit models.

```
var Route = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        context: '',
        beginTime: '',
        endTime: '',
        beginLocation: '',
        endLocation: ''
    }
});

var Trip = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Route,
    parse: function(data) {
        var out = [],
            last;
        _.each(data, function(route) {
            if (last) {
                out.push({
                    context: 'transit',
                    beginTime: last.endTime,
                    endTime: route.beginTime,
                    beginLocation: last.endLocation,
                    endLocation: route.beginLocation
                });
            }
            out.push(_.extend({ context: 'delivery' }, route));
            last = route;
        });
        return out;
    }
});
```

I have a sample fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/ccamarat/jMt8B/

Comment: This is perfect!  Very nice approach and the fiddle really helps.